# Weird reflections on normals

Tags: rendering, materials, normals

I'm new in blender and have recently started making a car model. Everything seems to be fine, but when I turn on the Material Preview, blurry and stretched reflections appear in some places. I suppose it may be related to autosmoothing, but I would like to find out from knowledgeable people how to solve the problem.
[image: Weird reflections]

Thats my material

[image]

Comment: Select your model in Object mode and Ctrl - A > Apply Scale. Then go into Edit mode, select All and Shift - N to recalculate the Normals. If that doesn't fix it, please share the Blend file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: @JohnEason Thanks for answer, but it didnt work. My blender file -> https://blend-exchange.com/b/aa0N8Jq9

Comment: I think you're just seeing reflections from the built-in HDRI in Eevee which is what is used in Material Preview mode. See what it's like in rendered view when you've set up the lighting.

Comment: @JohnEason I am actually making model for Unreal Engine, not for Eevee rendering. But anyway, it looks like I found a solution. After subdivision surface and UV-unwrapping(not Smart UV project), reflection looks little bit weird in Blender and Unreal, but generally it seems fine now. So, I guess my problem was the low-poly mesh and/or wrong uv-unwrapping. Anyway, thanks for help! I will comment if something goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You need to transfer the normals from high poly mesh (good topology) to your low poly mesh, make a vertex group ,with the vertices that need the fixes, then search in modifiers, propieties, data transfer. select the high poly mesh, and then face corner data, custom normals, and then select project, this should solve the issue.

you can find some tutorials looking for data transfer.